# Solve the datarow code?

Tags: c#, string, datarow

Below code raise error

```
DataRow[] dr = dt.Select("" + ColumnName + "='" + strLetter + "'" + " order by asc");
```

error is

> Missing operand after 'order' operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no column name to sort,
you need to pass column name which you need to sort

```
DataRow[] dr = dt.Select("" + ColumnName + "='" + strLetter + "'" + " order by " + ColumnName + " asc");
```